# Jquery, CSS three tiered menu populated by MYSQL, PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, css, drop-down-menu

Hi I'm trying to create a 3 tiered menu system, just a standard;

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>

</ul>
```

type system. I have three tables;

menu1 - name, link, type, position, order, status
menu2 - parent, name, link, type, position, order, status
menu3 - parent, name, link, type, position, order, status

I can get it working by putting a query inside the loop when selecting the first level menu items but that essentially runs a query on every single menu item (on a large menu system this is not a solution)

I've come up with this (non working) model (only shows the top level).

```
    <ul class="dropdown">
    <?php
    include('../../config/mysqli_connect.php');
    $q = "SELECT * FROM menu1 WHERE position = 'top' AND status ='yes'";
    $q2 = "SELECT * FROM menu2 WHERE position = 'top' AND status ='yes'";
    $q3 = "SELECT * FROM menu3 WHERE position = 'top' AND status ='yes'";

    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    $r2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q2);
    $r3 = mysqli_query($dbc, $q3);

        while($menu1 = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
            echo "<li><a href='" . $menu1['link'] . "'>" . $menu1['name'] . "</a></li>";

            while($menu2 = mysqli_fetch_array($r2, MYSQL_ASSOC))
            {
                echo "<ul class='sub_menu'>";

                if($menu2['parent'] == $menu1['name'])
                {
                    echo "<li><a href='" . $menu2['link'] . "'>" . $menu2['name'] . "</a></li>";
                }
                echo "</ul>";
            }
        }
    ?>
    </ul>
```

can someone help me out with an example of a working model or help me with my code. I'm approaching it wrong and need a push in the right direction. The other issue is that it shows the submenu ul whether there is a submenu or not.

Comment: What about sticking to one query, then you won't be in the labyrinth of so many loops?

Comment: yeah, that was the plan but i couldn't get that working either

Comment: I gave an example, but you maybe need to echo the $row['parent'] and `name`, they really might have no matches, if they are strings

Answer (score 0):

```
 <ul class="dropdown">
    <?php
    include('../../config/mysqli_connect.php');
    $q = "SELECT 

        tb1.link as 'menu1_link',
        tb2.link as 'menu2_link',
        tb3.link as 'menu3_link',
        tb1.name as 'menu1_name',
        tb2.name as 'menu2_name',
        tb3.name as 'menu3_name',
        tb2.parent as 'menu2_parent'

        FROM 

        menu1 as tb1,
        menu2 as tb2,
        menu2 as tb3,

        WHERE

        (tb1.position = 'top' AND tb1.status ='yes')
        AND (tb2.position = 'top' AND tb2.status ='yes')
        AND (tb3.position = 'top' AND tb3.status ='yes');";

    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQL_ASSOC))
        {
                ?>

            <li><a href="<?=$row['menu1_link'];?>"><?=$row['menu1_name'];?></a></li>
            <ul class='sub_menu'>";

                <?php
                if($row['menu2_parent'] == $row['menu1_name'])
                {
                ?>

                   <li><a href="<?=$row['menu2_link'];?>"><?=$row['menu2_name'];?></a></li>

                <?php   
                }
                echo "</ul>";
            }
   ?>
    </ul>
```

How about this way? Maybe if the tables should be JOINED, you could use proper joins (I don't know your table schema, so just select everything).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that query returns no results, even when the where clase is dropped.

Comment: my table structure is:
menu1 - name, link, type, position, order, status
menu2 - parent, name, link, type, position, order, status
menu2 - parent, name, link, type, position, order, status

i've tried 
SELECT menu1.name, menu2.parent, menu2.name FROM `menu1` LEFT JOIN `menu2` on menu1.name = menu2.parent but when i print_r the results i get this:

Array ( [name] => [parent] => )
1
Array ( [name] => [parent] => )
1
Array ( [name] => Sub Menu 1 [parent] => Test )
1
Array ( [name] => Sub Menu 2 [parent] => Test )
1
Array ( [name] => Sub Menu 3 [parent] => Test )
1